# Limiting Connections Per IP in IIS 6

Tags: iis, iis-6

I would like to limit the amount of connections per IP in IIS 6. This does not seem to be possible in IIS. Does anyone know of any solutions that would allow such a setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IIS6 cannot do this natively, but you could set something up which would allow you to do this such as a proxy, firewall, or some software such as [SafeSquid](http://www.safesquid.com/).

Just be careful because if there are browsers behind any sort of proxy, they will all appear to have the same IP.